# Convert string list of dict from csv into JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, csv, csv-import

I have a csv where for one column values are in list of dict like below

```
[{'10': 'i ve been with what is now comcast since 2001 the company has really grown and improved and delivers a great service along with great customer service ', 'aspects':['service']}, 
{'20': 'good service but lack of options to allow it be more affordable allowing individual channel choices would be great ', 'aspects':['lack', 'service']}, 
{'30': 'it a good service but very expensive', 'aspects':['service']}, {'40': 'good service', 'aspects':['service']}, 
{'50': 'good service but over priced ', 'aspects':['service']}]
```

Now because when I am reading this from `CSV` its a `string` I am not able to convert it to original type of `list of dict` and then `json` .

How I can actually achieve this .

Solution :

```
  data = output[output.aspects == aspect]['column1'].tolist()
  listData=ast.literal_eval(data[0])

  return json.dumps(listData)
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the data file, the code you use to read that data. It will help greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast
s = """[{'10': 'i ve been with what is now comcast since 2001 the company has really grown and improved and delivers a great service along with great customer service ', 'aspects':['service']}, 
{'20': 'good service but lack of options to allow it be more affordable allowing individual channel choices would be great ', 'aspects':['lack', 'service']}, 
{'30': 'it a good service but very expensive', 'aspects':['service']}, {'40': 'good service', 'aspects':['service']}, 
{'50': 'good service but over priced ', 'aspects':['service']}]"""

print(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'10': 'i ve been with what is now comcast since 2001 the company has really grown and improved and delivers a great service along with great customer service ', 'aspects': ['service']}, {'aspects': ['lack', 'service'], '20': 'good service but lack of options to allow it be more affordable allowing individual channel choices would be great '}, {'30': 'it a good service but very expensive', 'aspects': ['service']}, {'aspects': ['service'], '40': 'good service'}, {'aspects': ['service'], '50': 'good service but over priced '}]
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the built-in `eval`, but the one from `ast` is really a better idea.

Comment: @Gabriel. I did not mention `eval` because it can be dangerous sometimes  [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score -1):

To convert to json file:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dump(obj,open(path + '/txt.json','w+'))
```

Comment: That's better but it still only answers the second part of the question ;)

Comment: The first part is answered in previous answer with ast module. I do not want to repeat it ;)  @bruno desthuilliers