# Parsing a string list of dictionaries from csv files

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, file-io, csv-import

I have a folder of csv files I am parsing into a PostgreSQL database, for the most part it is relatively straightforward, but one of the values returns as a string but is actually a list of dictionaries like so:

EDIT: this is the structure of the value being read, it has a variable amount of entries, or sometimes none at all. this is a string, being read in by the csv reader object, as a value in a row

```
[{"Comment":"natural text here1", "Added By":"user1", "Made On":"Timestamp1"}, 
{"Comment":"natural text here2", "Added By":"user2", "Made On":"Timestamp2"},
{"Comment":"natural text here3", "Added By":"user3", "Made On":"Timestamp3"}]
```

it is not a valid json object, so you cannot json.loads() it.
I have also tried making it a json string

```
json_obj = '{\"%s\": %s}' % (columns[j], item)
```

to give me:

```
{
"Comments" : [
{"Comment":"natural text here1", "Added By":"user1", "Made On":"Timestamp1"}, 
{"Comment":"natural text here2", "Added By":"user2", "Made On":"Timestamp2"},
{"Comment":"natural text here3", "Added By":"user3", "Made On":"Timestamp3"}
]
}
```

which is a valid json object, but json.loads still throws a ValueError.

I'm doing something along these lines:

```
dir = 'file\\path'
files = os.listdir(dir)

for file in files:
  i = 0
  columns = []
  path = os.path.join(dir, file)
  with open(path, mode='rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore',
                        delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    for row in reader:
      j = 0
      dictionary = dict()
      if i == 0:
        columns = row
        i += 1
      else:
        for item in row:
          if columns[j] == "the column in question"
           #-------------------------------
           #trying to parse out this value
           #--------------------------------
          else:
            dictionary[columns[j]] = item
          j += 1
```

Essentially, this leaves me with a dictionary for each line of the csv file which I then push into the database. I'm sure that could be cleaner but its one and done code, the issue I am having is how to handle the string value that is actually a list. I'm sure there is some easy way to handle this that I am overlooking.

My first thoughts were to put the value into an empty list(under the assumption that would yield me an iterable list of dictionaries.) But that just gives me the list of characters in the string.

I also am unable to split the string by comma since the natural text field has punctuation.

any thoughts?

Comment: Is this JSON? If yes, please tag [json] and close it as duplicate of one of the many many json questions here. There are tons of json reader packages, some very performant. No need to write another.

Comment: I mean, it could be a list of json objects, but that doesn't help me parse it any better, because I can't make it a list and doing json.dumps on the whole string doesn't give me the ability to loop through the objects in the list.

Comment: You want `json.loads` not `json.dumps`. Yes it does allow you loop through the objects in the list. Please close this as a duplicate.

Comment: json.loads gives ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: **Post your code.** Include reproducible data.

Comment: what more code are you looking for? everything of relevance is in the question. The only thing I left out was the connection to the database, which is actually irrelevant. I feel like you haven't even read the question at this point.

Comment: There are [1,151 answers on "json list of dict"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+list+of+dict). Have you read them? I read your question multiple times and I'm telling you it's a duplicate.

Comment: you're aware that this value isn't actually a valid json object, right? why are you still harping on json when ai'm not actually dealing with a json object?

Comment: There are also many answers on "list of dict", "parse list of dict" and so on. Would you please do you your homework. This is a duplicate. Just pick the best of those duplicates, and close this in favor of it.

Comment: oh my god, you are somehow still missing the point. I don't have a list of dict, I have a string with the structure of one, and putting that string in a list geberator gives me the list of the characters, not the list of the dictionaries. I'm not asking how to iterate over a list of dict like 99.99% 9f the questions are, I'm asking if there is a method that will parse it into a list of dict so that I can iterate over it.

Comment: No I'm not missing the point, I'm addressing your question. `obj = eval(s)` works fine (or else `ast. literal_eval`), and was in one of the duplicates I cited you: [how to convert (string) list of dict from csv into JSON object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405766/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-from-csv-into-json-object-in-python). That's still a duplicate even if you don't care for the output to be json. You're asking how to parse a string containing a list of dict into a Python list of dict. `obj = eval(s)` or else `ast`. `eval` should be avoided for security reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert list of dict from csv into JSON object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405766/how-to-convert-list-of-dict-from-csv-into-json-object-in-python)

Comment: Do I get any thanks? There may well be other, better duplicates, but that was the first solution I found.

Comment: yes, thank you. I was marking the question as duplicate, though I still don't know why you spent an hour bickering at me about json.

Comment: I didn't spend an hour "bickering at you". I directed you towards a pile of duplicate solutions (and they apply regardless whether the input is legal json or not - just look at the general approach. And many of them are about parsing from string.). The keywords to answers I cited you half an hour ago led to the solution that I eventually posted you.